# Get a list of running web workers

Tags: javascript, web-worker

Is it possible to get an overview of running Javascript Web Workers either with browser console, developer tools or with a command?

I use an external library which uses workers and want to make sure it runs correctly, but I don't know how the worker is called and have no variable pointing to it.

Comment: You can use chrome dev tool. They are listed in scripts tab under web workers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can see the list of current workers using the developer tool in Firefox and Chrome (I'm not aware of other browsers).

In Firefox developer tools, they are in the right hand pane, under the `Workers` section of the `Debugger` tab.

[image]

In Chrome developer tools, they are in the right hand pane, under the `Threads` section of the `Sources` tab.

[image]

You can click on a worker to open up its console and debugger.

Hope it helps!!